# Labeling at specific place using Maplex?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, maplex

I have a bridge(.shp) point data which use symbol representation  and  I need to label it using field types and the label must be place under the second "ear"  like image below:

[image]

I already try using placement properties in maplex but the result is not really like i want,
[image]

[image]

Is there any way or any vb script that can i used in order to label it like i want?

Comment: In the label offset menu have you tried checking the box to 'measure offset from exact symbol outline'.

Answer (score 2):

Using a fixed position is not going to work as your symbols are all at different angles. Are they being rotated by an attribute? You can use that in your position - click Rotate by Attribute and select the rotation field that contains the angle for each feature.

[image]

Also, as others have suggested, use exact symbol outline, and you can increase the maximum offset. 200% should do in this instance, so Maplex can move the label a little further out when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using southeast orientation and checking the offset option to 'measure offset from exact symbol outline'.

[image]
[image]

Comment: After looking I'm not sure if 'Southeast' will work for all of your points you may have to try a few orientations.

Comment: i already try it and for some features its work but not for all data.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many features you have to label, you could try converting your labels to annotation, and move them to the exact position you need for each feature.

Comment: i have thousand of bridge data so if possible i would like to avoid using annotation or manually edit the label.thank you for your opinion, if i still don't have any solution i will used the annotation.tq

Comment: This wouldn't be a great solution then for that many features I agree.